# Php достать уникальное число из массива

Tags: php, массивы, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо с помощью регулярки вытащить единственное уникальное число с массива)

Вот код

```
 $num = array();// массив с дублями и уникальным числом

 for($i = 0;$i < 5001; $i++){  // генерим дубли
 array_push($num,22+$i,22+$i);
 }
 array_push($num,$uniq);// добавляем уникальное число в конец массива 
 shuffle($num);// перемешиваем массив
//print_r($num);
 foreach($num as $n){
  if(preg_match('/([\-]?[.\d]+)/is' ,$n)){
   echo $n;
  }
}
```

Как задать правильный код для поиска уникального числа в массиве?

Comment: Использование regexp для таких целей выглядит как забивание гвоздей паровым молотом. Задача определенно решается БЕЗ regexpos

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов суть как раз и заключается написать код с regexp, без array_unique)

Comment: Это очень ужасная суть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте array_count_values ($array) - она возвращает массив с количеством повторений, а дальше находите число, с одним повторением

```
<?php

$num = array(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7);
$count = array_count_values($num); 
print_r(array_keys($count, 1));

?>
```

результат:

```
Array ( [0] => 5 )
```

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае регулярные выражения неэффективны, что и показывает тест.

Программа:

```
$num = array();// массив с дублями и уникальным числом

for($i = 0; $i < 5001; $i++){  // генерим дубли
    $n = 22 + $i;
    array_push($num, $n, $n);
}
array_push($num, 21); // добавляем уникальное число в конец массива 
shuffle($num);          // перемешиваем массив
$start_time = microtime(true);
$numstr = array_map(function($n){return "$n";}, $num);
foreach($num as $n){
    preg_filter("/^".$n."$/", 0, $numstr, -1, $count);
    if($count == 1) break;
}
$timer1 = round((microtime(true)-$start_time)*1000, 3);
$start_time = microtime(true);
$uniq2 = array_flip(array_count_values($num))[1];
$timer2 = round((microtime(true)-$start_time)*1000, 3);
print "<br>Regular expressions: &emsp;uniq1 = $n&emsp; total_time = $timer1 ms&emsp; total points count =". count($num);
print "<br>array_count_values: &emsp;uniq2 = $uniq2&emsp; total_time = $timer2 ms&emsp; total points count =". count($num);
```

Результаты:

```
Regular expressions:  uniq1 = 21  total_time = 9758.314 ms  total points count =10003
array_count_values:  uniq2 = 21  total_time = 0.405 ms  total points count =10003
```

Попытка обрабатывать строку вместо массива проходит только для коротких строк, когда время некритично.